# JavaScript: calculate crazy decimal number returned from subtraction of two decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, math

I am making a service price tracker bot which will show something like this on price decrease:

```js
Service price decreased from 0.10 to 0.05

If you buy right now, you could save <x>
```

`<x>` is the substracted amount or safe amount (`oldPrice` - `newPrice`).

Code for subtraction:

```js
oldPrice - newPrice
0.10 - 0.05
// -> 0.05
```

While this works completely fine, but in some cases, if the service price (new or old) is like in more than 3 decimals e.g. 0.2184

The code will return weird full long number.

Examples:

```js
0.2184 - 0.1404
// -> 0.07800000000000001
0.09 - 0.085
// -> 0.0049999999999999906
2.159 - 2.0088
// -> 0.1501999999999999

/* Rare cases */
0.1764 - 0.1134
// -> 0.063
5.675 - 2.275
// -> 3.4
5.175 - 1.775
// -> 3.4
```

I obviously tried things like `Math.abs()` and use `String.replace()` to remove `00` and `99`, but nothing really works.

e.g.

```js
2.159 - 2.0088
// -> 0.1501999999999999

String(2.159 - 2.0088).replace(/[09][09]+/g, "");
// -> "0.1501"

0.2184 - 0.1404
// -> 0.07800000000000001

String(0.2184 - 0.1404).replace(/[09][09]+/g, "");
// -> "0.0781"
// -> Right: "0.780"
// -> Mistakes: 0.0 and 781 instead of 780
```

Note: I don't really care if the result is in string.

As you already saw above, it calculates wrong or essentially removes the main `9`s or `0`s.

Is there any other approach or it's the best one?

Comment: This is an issue with floating point numbers. It comes up in all programming languages and all operating systems. I would recommend you search github for a solution that fits your requirements: https://www.google.com/search?q=github+enhanced+floating+point+number+calculation

Answer (score 0):

Treat the numbers as integers, then divide:

(2184 - 1404)/10000
// -> .078